# Strange Behaviour w/ JavaScript workers

Tags: javascript

I created a JavaScript worker. When I visit the page in the browser it tries to print the page. Strange right? You can see the page in action here:

http://galesupport.com/fb/workers.php

Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The `print()` function (of the window object) in JavaScript prints the page, so it's not that suprising. Maybe you wanted `document.write` instead?